# Trouble Installing OpenFace in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, face-recognition, torch

I am new to deeplearning and face recognition. After searching, I found this python package about deeplearning applied to face recognition called OpenFace. From its documentation, I think it is build on top of Torch for the neural nets computation.

I want to install the package in a virtual environment, so basically these are steps I made:

1. brew install the necessary system requirements: bash,coreutils,curl,findutils,opencv, python and boost-python
2. Make a virtual environment and install dlib, numpy, scipy, pandas, scikit-learn, scikit-image
3. Cloned the openface github repository
4. Install Torch

   `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-deps | bash
   git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git torch --recursive
   cd torch
   ./install.sh
   source install/bin/torch-activate
   luarocks install csvigo
   luarocks install dpnn
   luarocks install nn`
5. cd to cloned openface repo and run 
   `python setup.py install`

However when I run python:

`>>>import openface`

I get:

`Segmentation Fault: 11`

How do I fix this? Also, are there any other tutorials for using openface?
How to properly install OpenFace?

Comment: I've seen seg faults coming from dlib and OpenCV conflicts, can you import these together without a segfault in a Python interpreter?

Comment: No, I can import opencv but I can't import dlib, it results to segmentation fault. Importing dlib alone still result to seg fault.

Comment: I think the segfault is happening because your system has multiple Python versions and dlib's C code is being compiled with a different version than the Python version used at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Brandon!,yes you're right, I have python 2.7 and python 3 installed in my system however the virtual environment I created for openface is only  linked to python 2.7, python 2.7 and 3 are installed outside the virtual environment. I am not familiar with dlib and how it is being compiled but basically I just pip installed it inside the openface virtual environment. So, what do you suggest me to do to fix it?

Comment: I think I made it work, I was able now to import openface, dlib and opencv without segfaults. I guess its the way of how dlib is installed, what I did is instead of using pip install, I clone the dlib's github repo and run `python setup.py install` inside. I don't actually know the reason for this, but it worked! Do you have any idea how pip installs dlib? Anyway, I think I'm good to proceed in exploring your amazing face-recognition package. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, this segfault was caused by compiling dlib with one Python version and running it with another. This was resolved by manually installing dlib rather than using their pip package.

Answer (score 0):

I installed dlib with pip for openface and had no problem importing it for Python 2.7:

```
[jalal@goku scratch]$ sudo /usr/bin/pip install dlib
[sudo] password for jalal:
Collecting dlib
  Downloading dlib-19.7.0.tar.gz (4.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.0MB 347kB/s
Installing collected packages: dlib

▽
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... done
Successfully installed dlib-19.7.0
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```